# How to concatenate list of strings with map reduce in scala

Tags: java, scala, scalding

I have a list of list of strings and I want to concatenate all the unique strings into a single (delimited space) string, something that `flatMap` allows one to do. However I am confused about the correct usage of the reduce function when concatenating 2 strings.

Input:

```
val listStrings: List[List[String]] = List(List("this", "is", "the"), List("this", "here"))
```

Expected Output (the order does not matter):
`String("this is the here")`

Comment: So, "this" is only supposed to appear once?

Comment: `listStrings.flatten.distinct.mkString(" ")`

Comment: I can only talk about the Java side of things (as this *is* tagged as Java). My first instinct would tell me to collect the the values into a set, then join by a space

Answer (score 1):

If you have colossal amounts of repeating strings to deduplicate, you likely need *two* steps:

- Map a list of strings to a set of strings (a trivial constructor invocation).
- Reduce a sequence of sets into one set (maybe even in-place merging is possible).

If you only have 2-3 entries, as shown in your example, @jwh's answer in comments suffices.